# Weight painting doesn't seem to affect model in pose mode

Tags: weight-painting

I'm having trouble rigging this character. I have it weight painted (seemingly) properly, but I still get the stretched mesh when trying to pose.[image: weight painted][image: stretched mesh]

Comment: I think you started out wrong. I don't think you want the (supposedly metal) parts of your robot to bend and deform. The way you usually do mechanical rigging is parenting the moving parts to the bone instead of weight painting if they are separate objects. Or if you have all parts in one object, parent it to the armature _With Empty Groups_, then in _Edit Mode_, select the group with the name of a bone, select all vertices of the mesh that should be controlled by the bone, make sure _Weight_ below the vertex groups is set to 1 and click assign. Do that for the other vertex groups as well.

Comment: To add to Gordon's post, if you really want your object to deform, activate the On Cage and Edit Mode options of your Armature modifier, select the vertices that are not correctly assigned, and assign them to the good vertex group in the Object Data > Vertex Groups list

Comment: thank you both! this solved my problem :)